# Como detectar se um ficheiro está em uso?

Tags: c#

Quero detectar se um ficheiro começado por algo (`javaw`) num determinado diretório está em uso ou não.

Answer (score 3):

Pode usar este método para fazer essa verificação:

```
protected virtual bool IsFileInUse(FileInfo file)
{
     FileStream stream = null;

     try
     {
         stream = file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
     }
     catch (IOException)
     {
         //O ficheiro não está disponível porque está a ser utilizado ou não existe.
         return true;
     }
     finally
     {
         if (stream != null)
         stream.Close();
     }
     return false; 
}
```

Utilize o método da seguinte forma:

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(path);
if(IsFileInUse(file))
{
    //está a ser utilizado
}
else
{
    //não está a ser utilizado
}
```

Adaptado desta [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2987576/2556111) do SOen.

**Edit:**

Como não sabe o nome completo do ficheiro use o método [Directory.GetFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), passando um *search pattern*, ele retorna um *array* de *strings* com os *paths* de todos os ficheiros que obedecem ao *search pattern*.

```
string[] dirs = Directory.GetFiles(@"oSeuDirectorio", "javaw*");
```

Depois utilize o método `IsFileInUse()` para cada um dos elementos do *array*

Comment: Eu já sabia disso, mas queria testar isso a um ficheiro cujo nome começa por "javaw".